# Make rounded bottom corners in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to make a CSS shape with a rounded bottom corner with `border-radius`, but failing to understand how to:

```css
.rounded-css {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: #669999;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rounded-css"></div>
```

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you would expect that CSS to give the results shown in the image, nor why you say "rounded top corner" and then show an image where the top is the only part that is a straight line.

Comment: Top corner or bottom corner?

Comment: Also, invalid color hex code

Comment: @A.Sharma I ment to say like a mountain top corner, i think yes should be a bottom one, just like the image.

Comment: You need to edit your question to show us that you at least understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Adjit Yes you are right missed one digit, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;` to make the whole bottom part round. With adding a white pseudo element `::after`, you can "cut" the unwanted upper part to only show the curve:

```css
.rounded {
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
  display: block;
  background: #669999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: -35px;
}
.rounded::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
  height: 35px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="rounded"></div>
```

Comment: Smth like this, just that when it has a bigger width gets sharper like in the image.

Comment: Updated the answer. Like this?

Comment: Yes, thank you, will mark as accepted. Asap.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help

Answer (score 4):

I think you can adapt this to the container you want to put this in. I think it's pretty much what you are looking for.

```css
.rounded-css {
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  border-bottom: 40px #669999 solid;
  border-top: 40px transparent solid;
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="rounded-css"></div>
```